# Image File on PHP doesn't display my uploaded image

Tags: php, file-upload

```
if (isset($_POST['submit2'])){

$file_name = $_FILES['file']['name'];
$file_type = $_FILES['file']['type'];
$file_size = $_FILES['file']['size'];
$file_tem_loc = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
$file_store = "function/upload/".$file_name;

$AAnimalName = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['Aanimal']);
$Abreed = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['Abreed']);
$Asex = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['Asex']);
$Acolor = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['Acolor']);
$Amark = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['Amark']);
$file_name = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_FILES['file']['name']);


$sql = "INSERT INTO adoption (AAnimalName, Abreed, Asex, Acolor, Amark, image)
 VALUES ('$AAnimalName', '$Abreed', '$Asex', '$Acolor', '$Amark', '$file_name')";
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);


if(move_uploaded_file($file_tem_loc, $file_store)){
    echo "";



 $folder = "function/upload/";

    if (is_dir($folder)){
        if ($handle = opendir($folder))
        {
            while (($file = readdir($handle)) !=false)
             {
                if ($file == '.' || $file = '..') continue;
                echo '<img src = "function/upload/'.$file.'" width = "250" height="250">';
            }
            closedir($handle);
        }
    }
 }
```

As seen in my code. The image upload is successful and stores exactly at "function/upload/" code on my display doesn't work. What i understand from the code that i have on the display part, I'm just trying to open a dir. Help anyone?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: @Marcs 2nd quote is the prob.

Comment: Your question is unclear, open this page for information on how to ask a good question on stackoverflow: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uploaded images display part of code is not working because of this line

**Your code**

```
if ($file == '.' || $file = '..') continue;
```

You miss one = symbol.

**Fixed code**

```
if ($file == '.' || $file == '..') continue;
```

Your code always uses a function "continue" and skips all results.
That is the reason you don't see any images.

Comment: Thanks! Got it already. How about displaying just 1 a single photo uploaded by a with the id of the form that has been submitted? My code displays the entire images in my folder.

Comment: To display last uploaded image use `echo '<img src = "function/upload/'.$file_store.'" width = "250" height="250">';` And no directory scaning is required.

Comment: I did this but the display is a broken jpg.

Comment: I got the correct code. I changed $file_store to $file_name.